# Javascript ... Displaying Values

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a blackjack card game in Javascript.  I appreciate your comments so far.
I'm looking for feedback as to why I can only seem to call the cardFace function once within the cardDealer function. At present cardFace(0) gives me a value whereas cardFace(1) or any other number does not UNLESS it is the only cardFace(x) being called within the cardDealer function.  Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks

Code below is not complete but I believe enough to discern enough information from.  Thanks

```
    function card(name, suit, face, value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.face = face;
        this.value = value;
    }

    aceOfHearts = new card("aceofhearts","hearts", "ace", 11);
    kingOfHearts = new card("kingofhearts","hearts", "king", 10);
    queenOfHearts = new card("queenofhearts","hearts", "queen", 10);
    jackOfHearts = new card("jackofhearts","hearts", "jack", 10);
    tenOfHearts = new card("tenofhearts","hearts", "ten", 10);
    nineOfHearts = new card("nineofhearts","hearts", "nine", 9);
    eightOfHearts = new card("eightofhearts","hearts", "eight", 8);
    sevenOfHearts = new card("sevenofhearts","hearts", "seven", 7);
    sixOfHearts = new card("sixofhearts","hearts", "six", 6);


    var deck;
    deck = [];


    deck.push(aceOfHearts);
    deck.push(aceOfDiamonds);
    deck.push(aceOfClubs);
    deck.push(aceOfSpades);
    deck.push(kingOfClubs);
    deck.push(kingOfDiamonds);
    deck.push(kingOfHearts);
    deck.push(kingOfSpades);
    deck.push(queenOfClubs);
    deck.push(queenOfDiamonds);
    deck.push(queenOfHearts);
    deck.push(queenOfSpades);
    deck.push(jackOfClubs);
    deck.push(jackOfDiamonds);
    deck.push(jackOfHearts);
    deck.push(jackOfSpades);
    deck.push(tenOfClubs);
    deck.push(tenOfDiamonds);
    deck.push(tenOfHearts);
    deck.push(tenOfSpades);


    var cardDealer = function()
    {  
        fisherYates(deck);

        document.getElementById("yourFirstCard").textContent = "Your First Card is " + cardFace(0) ;
        document.getElementById("yourSecondCard").textContent = "Your Second Card is " + cardFace(1) ;

    };

    var cardFace = function(x)
    {   
        cardFace = deck[x].face;
        return cardFace;
    };


    var cardSuit = function(x)
    {
        cardSuit = deck[x].suit;
        return cardSuit;
    };

    <body>
<div>Black Jack 1.1</div>
<br/>
<button type="button" onClick="cardDealer()">Deal</button> 
<div id="yourFirstCard"></div>
<div id="yourSecondCard"></div>
<div id="yourThirdCard"></div>
<div id="yourFourthCard"></div>
<div id="yourFifthCard"></div>
<div id="playerTotal"></div></div>
<div id="playerSit"></div>
<div id="playerMessage"></div>
<div id="sitter"><button type="button" onClick="sit()">Sit</button></div>
<div id="hitter"><button type="button" onClick="hitMe()">Hit</button></div> 
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="dealersFirstCard"></div></div>
<div id="dealersSecondCard"></div></div>
<div id="dealersThirdCard"></div></div>
<div id="dealersFourthCard"></div></div>
<div id="dealersFifthCard"></div></div>
<div id="dealerTotal"></div></div>
<div id="dealerSit"></div></div>
<div id="dealerMessage"></div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you refactor the whole thing before you keep working on it otherwise it'll be too late and you'll have to start all over again.

Comment: Do the other elements have any content at all? Like does `yourSecondCard` say "Your second card is of" or does it say nothing?

Comment: what are you upto? As suggestion, create 4 arrays heart, Club, Diamond and spade and then work with them,

Comment: where is your html code part?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I hope the re-edited version of the question is more helpful.  Refactoring is in the pipeline.  Thanks.

Comment: Move cardFace above cardDealer or change it to a `function cardFace(x)` definition, see if that helps.

Comment: You have two closing `</div>` tags on each of your `#dealer` `div`s. That's not on purpose, is it?

Comment: `aceOfDiamonds` is not defined. Your code stops working after added the first array item. Your deck has one item only (`aceOfHearts`).

Comment: Hi @Vlad I stated above that not all the code is listed.  I did this so it fits on the page.

Comment: @Web_Designer.  Thanks for this.  Will amend.

Comment: @dennmat I changed the function to function cardFace(x) as suggested and it worked.  Thanks very much.  Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I see the issue:

```
var cardFace = function(x)
{   
    cardFace = deck[x].face;
    return cardFace;
};
```

At first, you declare a variable called `cardFace` and assign it to a function. What this function actually does it reassigns your `cardFace` variable and returns it as a result. That's it, your function is gone now, you cannot refer to it anymore, since `cardFace` has been reassigned.

What you need to do is to change the body of the function that way it doesn't reassign the variable:

```
var cardFace = function(x)
{   
    var cardFaceValue = deck[x].face;
    return cardFaceValue;
};
```

The same goes for the `cardSuit` function.

Answer (score 0):

Move `cardFace` above `cardDealer` or change it to a `function cardFace(x)` definition.

This is a js behavioural thing. Functions defined in the format `function x` can be called from code written above it. Where as `var x = function()` cannot as it is determined at run-time.

See: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#4 for more examples by Mr. Resig.

Try out: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/ its a good thing to go through.

EDIT: Also there are a lot of good suggestions you should look into in this thread. Including the other posted answer. You should look into `scopes`.

**EDIT 2**

After looking at your code again I believe my solution was not in fact the correct one, as it slipped my mind that `cardFace` was being called inside the scope of `cardDealer` which means it would likely be defined by the time you call `cardDealer`. I therefore am thinking that when you changed it to `function` you may have made a name change, as the other answer suggests. And is infact the correct answer.

```
//Test function calling forward defined function
var f = function() { x(); };
var x = function() { console.log('a'); }
f()
>>> a

// Test function modifying it's own scoped name
var f = function() { f = 'test'; return f; };
f()
>>> "test"
f()
>>> TypeError: string is not a function

// Test function modifying it's own scoped name when declaring as function
function f() { f = 'test'; return f; };
f()
>>> "test"
f()
>>> TypeError: string is not a function
```